Are prime gaps of sizes 2 and 4 equally common?
Let $f(n,k)$ denote the number of prime gaps of size $k$ among the first $n$ prime gaps.
I was looking at the following ratio:
$$\frac{f\left(n,2\right)}{f\left(n,4\right)}$$
Computing up to $n=2^{26}$ suggest that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f\left(n,2\right)}{f\left(n,4\right)}=1$$
In other words, this would mean that gap sizes $2$ and $4$ are equally common. Assuming that there are infinitely many prime gaps of size $2$ and $4$, what do we know about the distribution of prime gaps that could confirm whether this result is correct ?
Computation results:



n
$f(n,2)$
$f(n,4)$
$f(n,2)/f(n,4)$




2^1
1
1
0


2^2
2
1
2.00000000


2^3
4
3
1.33333333


2^4
6
5
1.20000000


2^5
10
11
0.90909090


2^6
20
17
1.17647058


2^7
30
29
1.03448275


2^8
52
57
0.91228070


2^9
98
99
0.98989898


2^10
177
171
1.03508771


2^11
311
320
0.97187500


2^12
581
566
1.02650176


2^13
1053
1053
1.00000000


2^14
1981
1960
1.01071428


2^15
3691
3681
1.00271665


2^16
6906
6932
0.99624927


2^17
13215
13155
1.00456100


2^18
25003
24775
1.00920282


2^19
47300
47014
1.00608329


2^20
89878
89669
1.00233079


2^21
171188
170831
1.00208978


2^22
326968
326781
1.00057224


2^23
626555
626441
1.00018198


2^24
1202021
1202544
0.99956508


2^25
2311550
2312481
0.99959740


2^26
4452502
4452217
1.00006401




I think this follows from the first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Hardy–Littlewood_conjecture) and the fact that $p, p+2, p+4$ can't all simultaneously be prime.    But the first H-L conjecture is still unproven.

Due to Polymath project, there infinitely many primes such that  $P_(n+1)-P_(n)< or = 246$ where $ p_n$ is nth prime number

Well, the most important thing to say right off the bat is that the Twin-Prime Conjecture has not yet been proven. Without that your question cannot be answered.
The Twin-Prime Conjecture suggests that there are infinitely many twin primes (gap = 2). So, if that has not even been proven yet, it might be impossible currently to answer this question with assurance until that fact is known first.
There is currently not enough information regarding the prime gaps to answer your question yet, it remains unsolved. Although it appears the limit approaches 1 in your example, that is not enough proof to make a solid assumption either. You might want to look into the Hardy-Littlewood 1st Conjecture as well as it is relevant to this question. My argument is that if we don't even know how many twin primes there are how can we answer that question correctly?

In theory, a proof that the limit tends to 1 would not establish the Twin Prime conjecture, because it might be the case that there are finitely many gaps of size 2, and exactly the same number of gaps of size 4. It is hard to believe you would be able to prove the limit is 1 without either proving that fact or proving the TPC, but I suppose you could do proof by cases (i.e. prove the limit = 1 if TPC is true, and prove it's also 1 if TPC is false). I'm still quite skeptical, however.

As the twin prime conjecture is still open, I don't think one can easily prove whether this limit is equal to one.
However, there is a simple observation that explains why one should expect this to be true, namely that all primes beyond 3 are of the form $6k-1$ or $6k+1$ for some integer $k$. This means the prime candidates have gaps that just alternate between 2 and 4 and hence these occur equally often.

Slightly stronger even: Not only are the "candidates" spaced this way, but we also know that the ratio of primes of the form $6k-1$ and primes of the form $6k+1$ is equal to one. Heuristically, we could interpret that as both forms having the same "probability" to be prime. And if these "probabilities" were uncorrelated, that would imply OPs conjecture.

@Simon Do you have a source for that? It is almost certainly true but I don't know whether that would also be one of the universally believed but so far impossible to prove facts.

"Dirichlets theorem on arithmetic progressions" only implies that there are infinitely many primes of both forms. The fact that they are furthermore equally common is mentioned here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions#Distribution . A more precise version of that statement is given by the "Siegel-Walfisz theorem"
